# How to test cron job that runs every morning at certain time for Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, cron

My main config class:

```
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Job Scheduler class:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JobScheduler {
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1 ? * *")
    public void checkTransactionStatusInBank() {
        log.info("TEST 1");
    }
}
```

1. This job is meant to run every 01:01 AM every day.
   I set my OS date to 01:00 AM manually and then started my application. Works fine!
2. Again I manually changed date to next day and set time as 01:00 AM in OS. This time the scheduler is not triggered.

I could just run the application and wait for another whole day or is there any other effective way to test such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a test case for @Scheduled annotation. Spring team has already tested the cron functionality. You don't need to re-test again.

You need to write test case that will take the time as a parameter and inject the time into your checkTransactionStatusInBank() logic.